# Making a ListBox item go onto the next line

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Hello i currently have a list box, which when it reach the end of the list box it carries on writing rather then over flowing on to the next line, how do i get it to overflow onto the next line? or is that not possible?

Edit:
Sorry i forgot to mention windows forms.

Comment: Set [ListBox.HorizontalScrollbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.horizontalscrollbar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me i forgot to say windows forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are working with WinForms. In that case you will have to use a owner- drawn ListBox.

See e.g [An editable multi-line listbox for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2695/An-editable-multi-line-listbox-for-NET). It gives you an idea how you can do it.

Or this: [Multiline listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da/winforms/thread/ecec25b5-389c-4200-b6cb-f8dcb9ebf030)